# Converse of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, economics

I want to know if the following statement holds. It is *sort* of the converse of the CLT. Intuitively, my guess is that it is true. However, I have no idea on how to prove it.

Suppose that:

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)\overset{d}{\to}N(0,\sigma^2) $$

Where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Does it follow that $\hat{\theta_n}\overset{d}{\to}\theta$?

What are you thoughts?

Comment: Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to the same constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability).

So if $\hat{\theta}_n \to \theta$ in distribution was to hold, the convergence would also be in probability.

Maybe this can somehow be used?

Comment: The RHS is a normal random variable which is $O_p(1)$.